# connectivity between eclipse and robomongo

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb

How to view datas in robomongo that is written in eclipse using java?
I have intalled monjadb plugin also in eclipse but yet i am not able to view datas that i created using java in  java project.

[Details about libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pw5x.png)

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: i am not getting any error.it is show connected to database successfully in eclipse whereas i am not able to view it in robomomgo.

Comment: Why don't you insert some data into the new collection?

Comment: yes i have insert data in new collection.